# how to send object (or Json) from ajax to servlet

Tags: json

I want to send the Object from Ajax to servlet but Java just support to get the parameter and return "String", so that I cannot send and get an object from ajax to servlet. So any people can help me? Give me an example to send the json to servlet, please.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: I don't know how to send the json to servlet and how to receive the json data on servlet, that why I ask someone here and also research on google  to solve my problem but have no result :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: If you have a bit of code you're stuck on, add it to your question. If you're looking for a tutorial, there are many, try googling it.

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse in JS code itself

Comment: can you tell me how to using it? or give me a link that have an example or document about it, please :(